# How to get log4net to output to the same place as TestContext.WriteLine

Tags: log4net

How can I setup log4net to write to the Output window of MsTest?
The only function I've been able to output to that window with is TestContext.WriteLine, but I do not know if there is an appender that can do that. Trace and Console outputs do not work.

Comment: TraceAppender works for me.  Maybe you should post your log4net config when using TraceAppender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom appender that I could pass the TestContext to, and use the WriteLine method on that for logging.

Comment: Hi Josh, can you paste your custom appender code plus the config section please?

Answer (score 0):

To setup log4net to use the TestContext, I created a custom appender (NUnitLogAppender.cs):

https://gist.github.com/dropthemic/f360c389c35758bbb94e67b3aee09157

This is based off Console appender. To write to TestContext or TestContext.Progress, set the "Target" in NUnitLogAppender class.